# How to replace all previous values based on last value SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample data:

```
declare @T1 table 
            (
                ClaimID int, 
                Person varchar(20), 
                TransactionDate date,
                Status varchar(20)
            )

insert into @T1 
values (1, 'Person1', '2018-03-05','Open')
  ,(1, 'Person2', '2018-03-10','Open')
  ,(1, 'Person2', '2018-03-15','Closed')
  ,(2, 'Person3', '2018-03-15','Open')
  ,(2, 'Person3', '2018-03-23','Closed')
  ,(3, 'Person4', '2018-04-18','Closed')
  ,(4, 'Person5', '2018-04-23','Open')
  ,(4, 'Person5', '2018-04-25','Open')

select *
from @T1 t2
where TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
order by ClaimID, TransactionDate
```

Output will look like this:

[image]

I need to create a Boolean value column `is_Open`. For example `Person2`on a last `TransactionDate` had `Status "Closed"`, so value for this row  and all **previous** rows for `Person2` should be 0.

Same for Person3 - its been closed on `2018-03-23`, so all previous for Person3 should be 0.

But `Person5` has `Status` "Open" on the last TransactionDate, so the value for this (last transactionDate) should be 1 but for the previous TransactionDate should be 0 even if `status` is `Open`

**For column is_Open:**

If the last `TransactionDate` for `Person` has `Status` `Open`, then 1, all previous transactions 0. If the last transaction has Status Closed, then 0, and all
previous transactions 0.

**For column `is_Closed:`**

If the last `TransactionDate` for `Person` has `Status` `Closed` then 1 ,all previous transactions 0.If the last `TransactionDate` for `Person` has `Status` `Open`, then 0 and all previous transactions 0.

The result should look like this:

[image]

I tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LAST_VALUE` functions, but so far couldn't figure out:

```
select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by  ClaimID order by TransactionDate) as rowNum,
    iif(last_value(Status) over (partition by Person order by TransactionDate desc) = 'Closed', 1, 0) as LastValue
from 
    @T1 t2
where 
    TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
order by 
    ClaimID, TransactionDate
```

Comment: You can use the same logic used to transactions or parenthesis: open=+1 and close = -1 so just check the sum to get the actual state, ZERO or less mean it's closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would be the desired result isOpen checks the next row for the particular customer and if there is an open or closed status - closes the current row, same thins is happening with the isClosed , however in the opposite logic :

```
select *,case 
    when ClaimStatus = 'Closed' then 0
    when lead(ClaimStatus) over(partition by ClaimantID order by transactiondate asc) = 'Closed' 
        or lead(ClaimStatus) over(partition by ClaimantID order by transactiondate asc) = 'Open' then 0
    else 1
 end as is_Open
     from @T1
```

Also, this way is simplier and gives the same outcome. Correct me if I am wrong:

```
declare @T1 table 
            (
                ClaimID int, 
                Claimant varchar(20), 
                TransactionDate date,
                ClaimStatus varchar(20)
            )

insert into @T1 
values 
   (1, 'Claimant1', '2018-03-05','Open')
  ,(1, 'Claimant1', '2018-02-05','Open')
  ,(1, 'Claimant2', '2018-03-10','Open')
  ,(1, 'Claimant2', '2018-03-15','Closed')
  ,(2, 'Claimant3', '2018-03-15','Open')
  ,(2, 'Claimant3', '2018-03-23','Closed')
  ,(3, 'Claimant4', '2018-04-18','Closed')
  ,(4, 'Claimant5', '2018-04-23','Open')
  ,(4, 'Claimant5', '2018-04-25','Open')
  ,(5, 'Claimant6', '2018-05-18','Open')
  ,(5, 'Claimant6', '2018-05-23','Open')

select *,
iif(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Claimant ORDER BY TransactionDate desc) = 1 and ClaimStatus = 'Open',1,0) AS is_Open
from @T1 t2
where TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
order by ClaimID, TransactionDate
```

Comment: Thank you, @Serdia for the edit, however I must advise you that the code you chose is prone to errors, I saw what was edited by you and if you add one more job to the Person 1 for instance with an earlier date , they both shall remain closed. Furthermore, after running your code, doesn't Person 1 need to be with open Status ? If so, please revise the code again and make fit for yourself.

Comment: That is correct @Serdia, however have a look at the execution plan of both the queries, although much more readable code - the order by clause is applying a delay which can be evaded with the original query I had provided , its still your choice though and you can decide which one is solving your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_VALUE()` has no default framing, so you need to use window function:

```
select t2.*, (case when last_value([status]) over 
                        (partition by Person order by TransactionDate 
                         rows between current row and unbounded following
                        ) = 'Closed' 
                   then 0 else 1 
           end) as is_open
from @T1 t2
where TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
order by ClaimID, TransactionDate;
```

**EDIT :**

```
select *, (case when lastval = 'Closed' 
                then 0
                when lastval <> 'Closed' and cnt > seq
                then 0 
                else 1 
           end) as is_open,
          (case when lastval = 'Closed' and seq = cnt  
                then 1
                when lastval = 'Closed' and seq < cnt
                then 0 
                else 0 
           end) as is_close
from (select T2.*, last_value([status]) over 
                  (partition by Person order by TransactionDate 
                   rows between current row and unbounded following
                  ) as lastval,
                  count(*) over (partition by Person) as cnt,
                  row_number() over (partition by Person order by TransactionDate) as seq
      from @T1 t2
      where TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
     ) t;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the previous value for person5 should be 0. I edited picture.   My bed. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.*, (case when last_value([status]) over 
                        (partition by Person order by TransactionDate 
                         rows between current row and unbounded following
                        ) = 'Closed' 
                   then 0 else 1 
           end) as is_open,
          ( case when Status='Open' then 0 else 1 end )as is_Closed
from @T1 t2
where TransactionDate <= '2018-12-31'
order by ClaimID, TransactionDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, but for `Person5`  `is_open` should be 0 on` TransactionDate` `2018-04-23`

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I need.  All previous values for Person5 should be 0 in column `is_Open`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select claimid, person, transactiondate, status, 
if( lead(lastvalue) over(partition by person order by transactiondate ) = 'open', 0, 1) and if(lastvalue = 'open', 1, 0) as is_open,
if(status = 'open', 0, 1) as is_close
from 
(
select *, last_value(status) over ( partition by person order by transactiondate ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as lastvalue from sales.T1 ) T;
```

Here is output.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MKdH.png)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not how answer should look like.

Comment: Thanks much for checking on my answer. I missed to check your updated results and the additional query details. Here is the updated query. Can you check on this ?